# Restricting number of records allowed in a table in a way which can't be subverted

Tags: oracle, grails, licensing, oracle10g

We have a web application (Grails) which we are going to sell licenses for based on the number of users. There is a table in the database (Oracle 10g) which holds users. Customers will host their own copy of the software and database. Can someone suggest strategies for limiting the number of records which are allowed to exist in the user table in a way which can't reasonably be subverted by the customer? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should at least consider avoiding all technical means here and instead insisting that your customer sign an SLSA with an audit provision, and then audit here and there.

All these technical means introduce risks of failure, ranging from flat-out crashes to mysterious performance problems. The more stealthy and devious, the more stealthy and devious the bugs.

Comment: Very interesting suggestion @bmargulies, definitely something to consider.

Comment: In the agreements, make sure that you insist in a regular - yearly - audit that check the usage. Doing so prevents weird side effects and it allows the user to grow, what is good for the user and good for you, if you have a means to find this. The audit will work. Oracle does this and it is not always friendly but it works.

Answer (score 4):

It will depend on your definition of "reasonably".  If they're hosting the database, they'll always be able to allow more rows.

- The simplest possible solution would be an AFTER STATEMENT trigger that counted the number of rows and threw an exception if too many rows had been inserted.  They could, of course, drop or disable that trigger.  On the other hand, your application could also query the data dictionary to verify that the trigger was present and enabled.
- You could make it more difficult for them to remove the trigger by creating a DDL trigger that looked for statements that affected this trigger or the table in question and disallowed them.  That would require that the attacker find and remove that trigger as well before they could remove the trigger on the table.
- You could deliver a database job (`DBMS_SCHEDULER` or `DBMS_JOB`) that periodically ran, looked for the statement and DDL triggers and re-created them if they were missing.  The attacker could figure out that there was a database job that was recreating the objects and remove that job, then remove the DDL trigger, then remove the statement trigger.  In this job, you could potentially send a notification back to you (via email or http or something else) alerting you to the issue though that may be tricky from a networking standpoint-- your customer's firewall may not allow outbound HTTP requests from the database server back to your servers.
- If you have a license key that is being checked, you can embed the number of users allowed in that license key and bounce that against the number of rows in the table during the login table.

Comment: Thanks Justin! These are some great ideas. I'm going to have to do some research into license keys, do you have any suggested resources?

Answer (score 0):

If the customer doesn't have access to modify the table definition, you could use a simple set of constraints on the table:

```
CREATE TABLE user_table
(id   NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL
,rn   NUMBER NOT NULL
,CONSTRAINT rn_check CHECK (rn = TRUNC(rn) AND rn BETWEEN 1 AND 30)
,CONSTRAINT rn_uk    UNIQUE (rn)
);
```

Now, the column rn must take an integer value between 1 and 30, and duplicates are not allowed: thus, a maximum of 30 rows may be added.